# Why am I not able to provide constructor arguments to this Socket class?

Tags: java

When I try compiling this code I get various errors; the one which I'm most suspicious of is:

> constructor Socket in class Socket cannot be applied to given types

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Socket {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 6666);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to override `java.net.Socket` change your class name

Comment: Socket is your own class, not java.net.Socket. Don't call your class Socket.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've called your own class `Socket`, you'll need to use the fully qualified name to refer to Java's `Socket` class.

```
java.net.Socket s = new java.net.Socket("localhost",6666);
```

In the future, I would advise *against* naming your class something similar to what's in the existing API to avoid confusion like this.